# Wallpapers are scaling in time

Tags: android

Have some problem with wallpapers. This problem appear on some old and low-end devices. I'm trying to install wallpaper which may not scrolls(with device proportions) and they are normally installed. But after some time (2 or 3 days) wallpapers is scaling in 2 times(looks no pretty) and begin scrolling.
 
Here is part of code that install wallpapers:

```
public class WallpaperInstaller {

    private Context mContext;
    private CropImageView cropImageView;
    private ImageLoader loader;
    private boolean isCropped;

    public WallpaperInstaller(Context context, final CropImageView civ, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.cropImageView = civ;
        this.loader = imageLoader;
        this.isCropped = true;
    }

    public WallpaperInstaller(Context context, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.loader = imageLoader;
        this.isCropped = false;
    }

    public Thread setWallpaper(final String URL){
        Thread setWallpaperThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(mContext);
                try {
                    Bitmap croppedBitmap;
                    if(isCropped){
                        int scale = 1;
                        RectF rect = cropImageView.getActualCropRect();
                        int cropX = (int) rect.left * scale;
                        int cropY = (int) rect.top * scale;
                        int cropW = (int) rect.width() * scale;
                        int cropH = (int) rect.height() * scale;
                        croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loader.loadImageSync(URL), cropX, cropY, cropW, cropH);
                    } else {
                        try{
                            croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loader.loadImageSync(URL));
                        } catch (NullPointerException e){
                            loader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));
                            croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loader.loadImageSync(URL));
                        }

                    }

                    boolean isScrollable = croppedBitmap.getWidth() > croppedBitmap.getHeight();

                    if(isScrollable){
                        wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(-1, -1);
                        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(getWidth(croppedBitmap), getDisplay().getHeight());
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(croppedBitmap, getWidth(croppedBitmap), getDisplay().getHeight(), false));
                    } else{
                        wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(getDisplay().getWidth(), getDisplay().getHeight());
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(croppedBitmap, getDisplay().getWidth(), getDisplay().getHeight(), false));
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private int getWidth(Bitmap bitmap){
                return (int)((float)getDisplay().getHeight()*(float)bitmap.getWidth()/(float)bitmap.getHeight());
            }

            private Display getDisplay(){
                WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                return windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
            }

        });
        return setWallpaperThread;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding next lines:

`wallpaperManager.forgetLoadedWallpaper();
 wallpaperManager.clear();`